# PrimeFaces selectOneMenu used in dataTable significantly increases page size

Tags: jsf, primefaces, combobox, datatable, pageload

I'm using a PrimeFaces p:selectOneMenu in one column of a p:dataTable, the values in this selectOneMenu are populated using the value attribute:

`<p:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.menuValues}">`

The problems that the list that the menu is populated from contains a lot of values, say 0.1 MBs worth, and when rows are added to the dataTable the values for the selectOneMenu are replicated for each row.

So when a lot of rows are added (say 20+) the page size increases significantly and as it is refreshed each time a row is added it starts to take ages to add each new row.

Is there some way I can prevent this from happening? Possible use the same list of values for each menu in each row in the dataTable?

The pages are JSF 2 with PrimeFaces controls.

Answer (score 0):

You need to map all of them to the same backing list. Then instead of selectone use dialog. Dialog is added once and they press button to display dialog.

Comment: Cheers for the idea. Are you meaning Dialog as in a pop-up box?